# How to emulate an ARM architecture under OSX 10.6 ("Snow Leopard")?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, arm, emulation, qemu

I wish to emulate an ARM architecture (I wish to compile software for my DNS-323 NAS drive, to be more precise) and I'm having a hard time.

First I tried installing Q, which is an OSX port of QEMU. It freezes when I try to launch it.
Then I tried to download the source code for QEMU and apply a patch someone had written to compile QEMU under Leopard, but that isn't working either.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE:** looks like SkyEye project is (almost) dead now. It's still available on [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/skyeye/).

But **qemu** is better now. It can be installed from `macports` or `brew`:

```
brew install qemu
```

or

```
sudo port install qemu +target_arm
```

---

Try **[SkyEye](http://www.skyeye.org/)**. SkyEye is an Open Source Simulator, which simulates series ARM and [other Processor](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/skyeye/wiki/ProcessorList). The goal of SkyEye is to provide an integrated simulation environment in Linux and Windows. But it can be build for Mac OS X too.

I can't find complete information on Mac build, but check this:

- [SkyEye simulator 1.0.0 released! (Supports MAC OS/X)](http://www.ucdot.org/article.pl?sid=05/09/25/2319213)
- [[Skyeye-developer] Skeyey on Mac OSX initial fix](http://lists.gro.clinux.org/pipermail/skyeye-developer/2007-April/001210.html)
- [Problems with Skyeye the ARM simulator on Mac OS X](http://www.violentlyhappy.org/kazuya/yanetut/2007/11/problems-with-skyeye-arm-simulator-on.html)
- Google :)

Comment: Link is broken appears SkyEye doesn't exist.

Answer (score 12):

I was trying to get this running so I could check out the Raspberry PI OS under Mac OSX. I found this page:

http://cgi.cs.indiana.edu/~geobrown/stm32/Main/Simulation

The steps are:

1. Install macports
2. In a terminal, type: `sudo port install qemu +target_arm`

That's it!

Comment: For others trying to emulate the Pi with OS X + qemu, see http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/165/emulation-on-a-linux-pc

Comment: The only solution which just works. Thank you @yeeking.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [ARM Emulation With QEMU](http://www.goitexpert.com/general/arm-emulation-with-qemu/) using Q, the Mac port of [QEMU](http://www.qemu.org/download).

Comment: Thank you but as I mentioned in the third paragraph, I *did* try Q and it freezes for me under Snow Leopard.